# Stack Exchange copyright - where should we give attribution?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, attribution, creative-commons

I know that code from the Stack Exchange sites is licensed under [Creative Commons BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses).

So if I use code from Stack Exchange sites, attribution is required (as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) article).

How should I give attribution? Do I have to put a link in every source file, or is it enough, for example, to put the link in the README of the GitHub repository?

Comment: I am not a lawyer but I would put it in the code as a comment in each file which used it.

Comment: Note that following the rules in the linked blog post is not enough. The blog post [misses an important requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486/193139).